# How to convert bytes to integers

Tags: python, types

The output of my code is `b'19.3882`. How do I convert this to show only the integer output of `19`.

I tried `x=int(data)` but that doesn't work.
I also tried `x=int(data.stdout)` but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: The 'duplicate answer' does not answer his question IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Try making it a float first? I assume it's python3.

```
>>> data = b'19.3882'
>>> int(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'19.3882'
>>> float(data)
19.3882
>>> int(float(data))
19
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.